# One liner to copy folders (without files) from one location to another

Tags: linux, file, directory, copy, cp

I want to copy all the folders(without their respective content and sub-directories) from one directory to another.

My current relatively long solution is:

```
ls original/directory >> directory/to/copy/to/dirs.txt
cd directory/to/copy/to
xargs mkdir -p < dirs.txt 
rm dirs.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
ls -d original/directory/* | xargs -I{} mkdir -p "directory/to/copy/to/{}"
```